# SQL Server : split column based on parent child relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

The table has a parent child relationship between the two columns as below:

[image]

I would like to split the ID columns into 3 different columns as below:

[image]

Basically the one which has `0` as `ParentID` would be in `Cat1`. `Cat2` is linked with `Cat1` by `ParentID` and similarly `Cat3` is linked to `Cat2`.

If anyone has an approach to solve this could you please share your thoughts ?

Comment: Wich DBMS are you using?

Comment: It is SQL.Updated the title.

Comment: SQL is a Language... DB is where you are running your SQL Code...

Comment: which sql, `mysql` or `sql server`?

Comment: @Nifriz I dont know what difference a DB would make to this question. But it is MS SQL Server that I am using.

Comment: That's a basic double `LEFT JOIN` to do. Have you tried some queries on your own?

Comment: @Pradeep Different DB make possible to resolve the same problem in different ways. ;-)

Comment: Every RDBMS using a different dialect of SQL, @Pradeep . SQL Server, for example, uses T-SQL, Oracle uses PL\SQL, etc,etc. None of them follow all (or the same) ISO rules, and they all have different functions/syntax for the same behaviour. Stating you are using "sql" without telling us an RDBMS means that the volunteers can't give an answer without *guessing* which you're using, and then you may get answers that don't work on the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple query to do. And you've actually perfectly described what the query should do.

Let's go step by step:

> Basically the one which has 0 as ParentID would be in Cat1.

So the first step is to get `Cat1` values:

```
SELECT Cat1.id FROM tablename AS Cat1
WHERE Cat1.ParentID = 0
```

> Cat2 is linked with Cat1 by ParentID

It's a `JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` to be specific, because apparently you want to get rows with `null` values in these columns, if there are no rows with such `ParentID`:

```
SELECT Cat1.id, Cat2.id FROM tablename AS Cat1
LEFT JOIN tablename AS Cat2 ON Cat2.ParentID = Cat1.id
WHERE Cat1.ParentID = 0
```

> similarly Cat3 is linked to Cat2.

Now, we do the same for `Cat3`:

```
SELECT Cat1.id, Cat2.id, Cat3.id FROM tablename AS Cat1
LEFT JOIN tablename AS Cat2 ON Cat2.ParentID = Cat1.id
LEFT JOIN tablename AS Cat3 ON Cat3.ParentID = Cat2.id
WHERE Cat1.ParentID = 0
```